# how to set the selected option of a select element without triggering a change event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, html-select

I'm currently using this on a select:

```
var sortNo = $('select[name=anzahl_eintraegeSEL]');

sortNo
    // set selected based on hidden input default value
    .find('option[value="'+ $('input[name=anzahl_eintraege]').val() +']')
    .attr('selected', 'selected').attr('set',true)
    // set up change listener
    .on('change', function(){
        // do sth
        });
```

I want to set the default option to selected without triggering an initial change event.

How can I get this to work? The above seems to trigger a change event right away.

Thanks for help!

Comment: handle the event on the control and cancel propagation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
sortNo.on('change', function(){
    // do sth
}).val($('input[name=anzahl_eintraege]').val()); // set default value from hidden field
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/nWwkY/2/)

Comment: Sorry, I need to get the value from the hidden input. this doesn't help

Answer (score 1):

for once: In this line:

```
.find('option[value="'+ $('input[name=anzahl_eintraege]').val() +']')
```

You are missing the closing '"'. Should be:

```
.find('option[value="'+ $('input[name=anzahl_eintraege]').val() +'"]')
```

Next your .on() is executed while jQuery has your  tag on top... I guess you want the change of the , not on the .

And you don't need to find the option tag yourself, jQuery can do that for you, using sortNo.val().

I believe that is what you want?: http://jsfiddle.net/KadrG/

Comment: Thanks for the typo. I tried this, it also work, but the above is more what I need!